# How to knockout a pdf file using iText7 C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, itext7

[src_pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiHlqmpXn1YA8HLR8?e=Fcd7n4)
I wan to knockout a pdf file using iText7 C# with:

```
var sourceFPath = @"to_knockout.pdf";
var targetFPath = @"out.pdf";
using (PdfDocument origPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFPath)))
{
    var currPage = origPdf.GetPage(1);
    using (PdfDocument destPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetFPath)))
    {
        var page = destPdf.AddNewPage(new PageSize(100 * 72f / 25.4f, 125 * 72f / 25.4f));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        PdfFormXObject xObject2 = currPage.CopyAsFormXObject(destPdf);
        PdfTransparencyGroup transGroup = new PdfTransparencyGroup();
        transGroup.SetKnockout(true);
        transGroup.SetIsolated(false);
        xObject2.SetGroup(transGroup);
        canvas.AddXObjectAt(xObject2, 0,0);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

[wanted_pdf](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18UiHpZX_lv5raV6otE?e=YVYSeC)

Comment: @mkl Is there any way?

Comment: When you say you _want to knockout a pdf_, what exactly do you mean? What process could transform your `to_knockout.pdf` into your `knockouted.pdf`? As far as the PDF contents therein are concerned, those two files are only remotely related. And what you see as result of your code, is exactly what is to be expected when making the page content of your PDF a knockout group.